# Why is this writing to a file incorrectly

Tags: python-3.x

Im writing some code for my schools sign in/out system and im kind of confused with the output im getting
In essence im checking each line of students which looks like 'name theircode' for each student and checkign it aganist the input code which all works
but when im printing in logged times it rewrites the previous line.
how do i fix this?

Here is the code

```
import time
lunch = str('inout {0}.txt'.format(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
while True:
    variable = input()
    with open ('students.txt') as f:
        for eachline in f:
            name,rfid = eachline.rsplit(None,1)
            if variable == rfid:
                print("yay")
                with open('inout.txt','w+') as fp:
                        log = str('{0} loggged at {1}(ID: {2})'.format(name,time.strftime("%H:%M"),rfid))
                        fp.write('\n')
                        fp.write(log)
            else:
                print("nope")
```

Comment: `open('inout.txt','w+')` -> `open('inout.txt','a+')` Your file is recreated at each iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much. I dident even think about that XD, im kinda new to coding